# Error getting on Appium, Cannot set the element to 'value'. Did you interact with the correct element?

Tags: android-emulator, appium-android

I am doing automation of the app using appium. I am able to lunch the app but I go for login, it can read the XPath for login. But appium is unable to enter the mobile number. For mobile device, I am using the emulator.

This is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("mobile"))).sendKeys("123456");
```

This is my Xpath:

```
mobile=//android.widget.EditText[@text='Mobile']
```

Error facing:

> > Encountered internal error running command: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Cannot set the element to 'value'. Did you interact with the correct element?

Comment: It might be the field has some special input validators, which prevent sendKeys method to work properly on it. Tried to send the text via actions 1 or via mobile: type (the latter is only available since v. 1.17 or in appium@beta)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the `props.getProporty` in there or what you trying to do with that, you can just use the xpath right in the `driver.findElement()`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Mobile']")).sendKeys("123456");
```

Comment: It's not an issue whether I use props.getProperty. My issue is My emulator is unable to read the sendKeys value.

Comment: are you using `click()` on the element before you do your `sendkeys` command?

Comment: This has been fixed. I sent the text via actions.

Answer (score 0):

In UIAutomator2 mode, if the element is not an editText， can‘t use `sendKeys()/setValue()`
Can user `driver.pressKey(KeyEvent(AndroidKey.A))` instead

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to access should be of editText to accept input keys. if you are getting parent element of the editText, there is a chance that you are trying to sendKeys to a layout field than actual element. Inspect the element retrieved in the Appium Desktop session